# Scanner nextLine Java error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want a program in java to accept

1.Integer

2.Double

3.String 
respectively .
and display the above .

But the problem I m facing is after I enter integer and double its not prompting me to enter String . Its directly display the values . 
As i searched the soln to this , I got to know that

```
scan.nextLine();
```

should be used after I accept the double value .

can anyone tell me why should use this line .
I read the doc of nextLine . But I didnt understand .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        //   scan.nextLine();            **Why should I write this ??**
        String s = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: because It takes the new line character as an input string.

Comment: Just asking, when you insert a Double, what do you digit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `nextLine()` javadoc:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.

After input of double value, `nextLine()` reads the remainder on the line containing the double number. That's why you need another `nextLine()` for input string.

Using `next()` would solve your problem:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = scan.nextInt();
double d = scan.nextDouble();
String s = scan.next();

System.out.println("String: " + s);
System.out.println("Double: " + d);
System.out.println("Int: " + i);
```

Comment: Thanks . I thought that after double it simply goes to the next line .